# Bivariate Poisson Distribution: Covariance Parameter

Tags: probability

I've been having a look at the probability distribution function of the Bivariate Poisson with rates lambda1, lambda2 and lambda3 with lambda3 being the covariance between lambda1 and lambda2. As far as I know all three have to be positive- why is this the case? I know by definition of Poisson rates the rates have to be positive, but just by looking at this equation it seems plugging in negative numbers for lambda3 still produces solutions (link, Page 2 Equation 1):

http://isc.temple.edu/economics/wkpapers/Airports/MVPoisson/Karlis_Ntzoufras_Statistician.pdf

Can someone enlighten me? I have no access to academic papers so finding out the answer is a bit difficult...

Comment: Negative $\lambda_3$'s could possibly make $(1)$ negative, and hence not a probability.

Comment: In that case what is the range of this probability function? Is it all positive values of lambda1, lambda2, lambda3 and some negative lambda3 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OP wrote:  .... *lambda1, lambda2 and lambda3 with lambda3 being the covariance between lambda1 and lambda2. As far as I know all three have to be positive- why is this the case?*

This is due to the way this bivariate Poisson is actually constructed.

Using the authors' notation, let $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ be mutually stochastically independent Poisson random variables, with positive parameters $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$, respectively, and pmf's $g_i(x_i)$ for $i={1,2,3}$.
THEN, a non-trivial bivariate Poisson distribution is the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ where:

$$X = X_1 + X_3,... and ...  Y = X_2 + X_3$$

The parameters $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ are positive because they are the individual Poisson parameters of the underlying parent distributions.

Moreover, $Cov(X,Y)$ = $Cov(X_1 + X_3, X_2 + X_3)$ = $Var(X_3)$  ... by independence.

And since $X_3$~Poisson($\lambda_3$), we know that $Var(X_3) = \lambda_3$.